# Decrypt with Fernet [Python]

Tags: python, encryption

I am currently working with a login system and I want to decrypt a password that is stored in my database (It is encrypted from the beginning)

I've tried this:

```
from cryptography.fernet import Fernet

key = Fernet.generate_key()
cipher_suite = Fernet(key)

# THIS IS STORED IN MY DATABASE FOR EXAMPLE
password = "gAAAAABWC9P7-9RsxTz_dwxh9-O2VUB7Ih8UCQL1_Zk4suxnkCvb26Ie4i8HSUJ4caHZuiNtjLl3qfmCv_fS3_VpjL7HxCz7_Q=="

passwordChosen = password.decode('utf-8')
decryptedPasswordDB = cipher_suite.decrypt(passwordChosen)

print(decryptedPasswordDB)
```

I'm getting the error "InvalidToken"...

I want the decryptedPasswordDB varaible to print the actually password.

I appreciate all the help. Thanks.

Comment: Is 'key' the key that was used to encrypt the password originally?

Comment: No. I do not know how to do that..

Comment: You must have the same key when encrypting and decrypting - https://cryptography.io/en/latest/fernet/#cryptography.fernet.Fernet.generate_key - if you don't have the original key you can't decrypt the password.

Comment: How do I save the original key?

Comment: You could save it in a file, or in a database table.  If you have a large budget there are specialised applications for managing secret information.  The important things are that: your code is able to access it; unauthorised persons are not able to access it.

Comment: Some relevant discussion [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/220950/where-to-store-the-private-key).  Note that it's tempting to store the key in you code, but this means your key would be exposed if, for example, you uploaded your code to Github - there are bots constantly searching github for secrets like this.

Answer (score 2):

First, decrypt then decode

```
passwordChosen = cipher.decrypt(password)
decryptedPasswordDB = passwordChosen.decode('utf-8')
```